# ColdFusion memory usage for Components

Tags: memory-management, coldfusion, javabeans

I am creating a site using VMC and using beans to transfer the data from the Model to the Controller/Views.

I plan to implement some basic and very simple caching that will store the beans in a simple struct if they have not changed (as usage grows, we will implement a better caching system around ver 1.3).

So the question goes to what goes in our bean.

One type of bean would only hold the basic data and would rely on some outside service to do the rest of the work (contacting the DAO to get the query, parsing the query to load the bean values). This is the "anemic bean" model as I have been told repeatedly by a co-worker :-).

Another type of bean would be more self-contained. It would know where the DAO is so would call the DAO directly to get the data query. It would contain necessary functions to parse out the query and set the properties. It would basically combine much of the "service" layer with the bean, leaving the direct database in the DAO layer.

Of course, to the controller/views, both beans would look and act the same.

But the question is memory and how ColdFusion/Java deals with it.

With the anemic model, the bean would just have enough memory to hold the property variables with just a touch more to let it point to the Service when it needs to.

With the heavier functions in the second type bean, would it take up more memory in the cache??? Would each copy of the bean have a full copy of the methods?

I tend to think that the second model would not have much more memory since they would "share" the methods and would only need memory for the property variables.

IMHO the second method would simplify the codebase, since the code the bean needs would be closer to the bean rather than scattered between the DAO and Services. And it would reduce simple functions in the Service that merely pass along calls to the DAO of the bean could go directly to the DAO when it needed it...

Does the question make sense?? Or at least how I am asking it?

Comment: The question makes sense.  You just need somebody smarter than me to answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the memory management is handed at Java level, so it follows the same rules. In Java the only "new" memory that's allocated when an object instance is created is for its member variables; there is not memory foot print for the methods of the component/class itself: that stuff is only stored in memory once, with a reference back to it.

One possible consideration is that each method of a CFC is compiled as its own discrete class (why? I don't know), so each method is its own class. This will perhaps mean a slightly larger memory footprint for CFC usage compared to Java class usage, but this will still not be something that scales with object-instantiation: each instance of an object will still just consume memory for its member variables, not the methods of the CFC that defines the object.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking was happening with the methods. I did not think CF/Java would be silly enough to re-compile and store the methods with each instance.

Comment: own discrete class because you can assign any method to any object in CFML? Just guessing

Answer (score 0):

all cfm pages are compiled to memory by default, a CFC needs to implicitly be stored in memory (application scope for example) in order to avoid instantiating it each time, however you do it requires the same memory for the same component, any additional usage will depend on any data you are storing within your component or bean.
Have you had a look at ColdSpring ?

Comment: Yep. Using ColdSpring for IOC. Good stuff. Looking into ColdBox for overall framework.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes mainly from an FW1 framework perspective, but I am guessing that maybe you are using this or, at least, aware of it:

https://framework-one.github.io/documentation/4.3/developing-applications/

The bean should really only be a set of properties.
The bean is also transient.
So, you create new instances of a bean, per DB table row:

```
// beans/user.cfc

component accessors=true {

    property id;
    property uuid;
    property firstName;
    property lastName;
    property email;
    property departmentId;
    property department;
    property createdAt;

}
```

The tblUser DB table would map to this, like:

```
// tblUser

id; [autoincrement]
uuid; [for use in API requests]
firstName;
lastName;
email;
departmentId;
department;
createdAt [created automatically, when a record is inserted]
```

My approach, using FW1, is to create a state variable in each service, like:

```
// services/user.cfc

component accessors=true {

    variables.users = createObject(“java”,”java.util.LinkedHashMap”).init(); // <= ACF11 or an ordered Struct ACF11+

    function init( beanFactory ) {
        …
    }

    …
}
```

Then I set a maximum limit for how many beans can be stored in:

```
variables.users
```

In order to maintain the correct amount of beans, in the state variable, I do something like this in the service:

```
function save(user){
    …

    if  ( StructKeyCount( variables.users ) GT request.maxUserBeanCount )  {                
        local.count = Val( StructKeyCount( variables.users ) - request.maxUserBeanCount );
        local.keylist = StructKeyList( variables.users );
        local.keyArray = ListToArray( local.keylist ).filter( ( val, idx ) => idx <= local.count );
        local.keylist = ArrayToList( local.keyArray );
        for ( local.key in variables.users )  {
            if ( ListFindNoCase( local.keylist, local.key ) ) {
                StructDelete( variables.users, local.key );
            }
        }
    }
   
    …

    return userid;
}
```

I would say that a good maximum value is around the 500 mark:

```
request.maxUserBeanCount = 500;
```

Beans are quite small, so they shouldn’t take up too much room, depending on how many properties, you have, in each?

Clearly, you will need to implement a mechanism, for adding new items, if it exists in the DB, but not in the user bean Struct.
When using the service get() method, check for the existence of the bean in the user bean Struct, first and if it has been removed from the front of the Struct, then obtain it from the DB, and add it back to the user bean Struct.
The user bean Struct is purely used as a caching mechanism, but you don’t want it to balloon to a size that will start to affect the performance of the application.